# How to perform a map operator inside a ngrx's affect?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

I would like to perform a mapping operator on a given string property in order to make it a Date object, because the FooModel is being sent with the format of `{ "id": 1, "start": "2020-12-15T16:00:00.000Z" }`

```
export interface FooModel {
  id: number;
  start: string;
}

export class FoosService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  all() {
    return this.http.get<FooModel[]>(BASE_URL);
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class FoosApiEffects {
  constructor(private foosService: FoosService, private actions$: Actions) {}

  loadFoos$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(FoosPageActions.enter),
      exhaustMap(() =>
        this.foosService
          .all()              
          .pipe(map(foos => FoosApiActions.foosLoaded({ foos })))
      )
    )
  );
}
```

This is works as expected but when I'm trying to map the foos in odrer to get the `start` property as Date object like:

```
foos.map((foo) => foo.start = new Date(foo.start)
```

inside the affects:

```
  loadFoos$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(FoosPageActions.enter),
      exhaustMap(() =>
        this.foosService
          .all()          
          .pipe(map(foos => {
            return FoosApiActions.foosLoaded({ foos.map((foo) => foo.start = new Date(foo.start) }
          )
        }))
      )
    )
  );
```

I'm getting an error of:

> Argument of type '{ foos: FooModel[]; "": any; }' is not assignable to
> parameter of type '{ foos: FooModel[]; }'.   Object literal may only
> specify known properties, and '(Missing)' does not exist in type '{
> foos: FooModel[]; }'.

What is the correct way to use the property mapper inside the affect?

Comment: You need to return something from the projection function you pass to `map(foo => { foo.start = ...; return foo; })`

Comment: Hey @martin thank you but I'm already returning the `.pipe(map(foos => { return FoosApiActions.foosLoaded({ foos })`

Comment: martin is right, you aren't returning anything.  Try this: `return FoosApiActions.foosLoaded({ foos: foos.map(foo => ({ ...foo, start: new Date(foo.start) })`

Comment: Once you change your start from a string to a date it no longer matches the FooModel interface. Is the props in your action expecting a FooModel[]?

Comment: Hi @DeborahK, Im in the middle of your course, yes so maybe I'll will need another property?

Comment: :-) Yes, another property in the interface defined of type 'date' could help. (Be sure to define it as optional.)